# Why do my .ogg files play in my browser on my local drive but not in my browser when i upload them to my web server?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am trying to display the same audio file five times for a proof of concept for a friend and the website works fine on my local drive but when i load the site in a browser the htmnl document will come up with five null depictions of the file. I have my site at http://www.knowledgenation.us/CloudCity this baffles me because the code is simple enough

Thisi is where audio will go.

I dont know where to even begin to trouble shoot this little annyoying error.

nicholas

Comment: What web server are you using? It may not be serving the OGG files with the appropriate MIME Type for the browser? Also make sure your page is using a relative URL for the file rather than an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I had to find a proper MIME type for my web hosting company in India. They thought the technology did not exist but I found it by asking a question at the Ogg Vorbis chat room. It wasnt as difficult as I thought it would be to answer. THank you.